Can std::ranges::enumerate enumerate any possible valid C++ array?
Once I asked whether std::ranges::views::enumerate uses the wrong type (long) for indexing on GCC, but apparently that's not the case, because

std::views::enumerate is specified to use range_difference_t<Base> as its index value.

However, from the draft

The type size_t is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object ([expr.sizeof]).

So one can think of an array so long that the trailing elements from some index onward don't fit the type used by enumerate for indexing, while still fitting std::size_t by definition, provided on a given machine, the following holds
static_assert(std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() > std::numeric_limits<long>::max());

For instance, such an array would be this:
std::vector<int> v(std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max());

for which I'd wonder how k in the following evolves:
auto w = v | std::ranges::views::enumerate;
for (auto [k, _] : w) {
    std::cout << k << std::endl;
}

Unfortunately, std::vector doesn't seem to allow that size at all, throwing an exceptions, wheras a std::array with that same size isn't even compilable (full example here), but I assume that neither behavior is mandated by the standard. Or is it?

As the exception tells you, vector's max possible size is defined by std::vector::max_size(). At worst it's std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / sizeof(T), not sure if any standard library implements smarter heuristics.

I've worked on machines that used a segmented architecture.  On such a machine, a std::size_t could be unsigned 16-bit, even though a (far) pointer would be 32-bit.  I've worked on machines that used a banked architecture (4K banks).  On such a machine, a std::size_t could be unsigned 12-bit (but would probably be unsigned 16-bit), even though a (full) pointer would be 24-bit (12-bit bank number, 12-bit offset).  Modern C++ is available for both those architectures — even though only used by hobbyists for funsies.

std::array<int, std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()> isn't compilable for a good reason. sizeof such a type would be at least std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() * sizeof(int), which wouldn't fit in size_t, whereas size_t is supposed to fit the size of any object. Vector of this size probably can't work for a similar reason - at the end of the day, it would need to allocate an array this big, and an array is an object whose size must again fit into size_t. (Setting aside the practical considerations of your machine likely not having this much RAM).

No, it is possible that enumerate can't enumerate all elements of an array.
But that isn't anything unusual. It is a general problem that has always existed in C and C++.
For example if std::size_t and std::ptrdiff_t have the same bit width and the implementation actually permits objects to have the size std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max(), then
char arr[std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()];

will be valid, but std::numeric_limits<std::ptrdiff_t>::max() will be smaller than the maximum index of the array. range_difference_t for the array is also std::ptrdiff_t and so enumerate will eventually overflow causing undefined behavior.
However, the exact same problem occurs with any form of pointer differences into the array, not just enumerate. For example &arr[std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()-1] - &arr[0] also has type std::ptrdiff_t and then has undefined behavior because the value is not representable.
So, practically speaking, the implementation can't allow arrays that are larger than the maximum value of std::ptrdiff_t (instead of std::size_t) in order to avoid completely breaking the standard library and a lot of user code.
The same applies to the use of size_type and difference_type in ranges/containers. In practice the maximum permitted size must be limited to the maximum of difference_type (rather than size_type) to avoid these UB edge cases from being possible. There is no guarantee that the size of a container can reach the maximum value of size_type. Containers usually have a max_size member function to tell the actual maximum size.
All of this is why a common opinion is that size_t/size_type was a mistake and that everything should have been defined with ptrdiff_t/difference_type as basis instead. I guess that opinion is also why the choice to use difference_type in enumerate (and other views) was made.
